# Visual studio 2005 c++ autoincrement version in resources

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2005, version, auto-increment

Is it possible with some code or another way to increment the last number of the version each project buld?
I use a resources.rc and resources.h to store the version.

Comment: You can insert a `#include` in the appropriate place in your .rc file, then it becomes trivial to write a program to update the included file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I successfully used [RCStamp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/rcstamp.aspx) in the past. Perhaps something to check out.

Comment: Note that the version linked blindly assumes that .rc file is ANSI encoding. VS2010 generated mine in UTF16, so the tool was not happy. After I resaved them as ANSI, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[Auto_Increment_Version](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Auto_Increment_Version.aspx)

Comment: As already pointed out, the code works for .net. The question is about C++ and Win32 which uses completely different tooling for versioning binaries.